# GNU M4 seems to access unnecessary value in ifelse

Tags: linux, gnu, m4

I'm trying out the m4 CLI on linux and trying to create a for(begin, end, step) macro that will print out a comma separated list of numbers in the given range. I also want it to support a default step of 1. I tried the following

```
[tom@sp4 ~]$ m4
define(`for',`ifelse($#,2,`for($1,$2,1)',eval($1+$3>$2),1,$1,`$1, for(eval($1+$3),$2,$3)')')

for(3,9)
m4:stdin:3: bad expression in eval: 3+>9
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

While it works OK I can't understand why I get the error message as $3 is only blank on first pass. Why is it even bothering to read the eval($1+$3>$2) when $#==2?

EDIT: Using the information William gave me in his answer I've came up with the macro below. It accepts 0 to 3 parameters and allows count down as well as up. I have learned a lot from messing with this one example.

```
[tom@sp4 ~]$ m4
define(`for',
    `ifelse(
        $#,0,``for'',
        eval($#==1 && $1+0>0),1,`for(1,$1,1)',
        $#,1,,
        $#,2,`for($1,$2,ifelse(eval($1+0>$2+0),1,-1,1))',
        eval($3+0==0 || $3+0>0 && $1+0>$2+0 || $3+0<0 && $1+0<$2+0),1,,
        eval($1+0+($3+0)ifelse(eval($3+0<0),1,<,>)$2+0),1,$1,
        `$1, for(eval($1+$3),$2,$3)'dnl
    )'dnl
)


for
for
for(0)

for(5)
1, 2, 3, 4, 5                
for(5,-23,-5)
5, 0, -5, -10, -15, -20                    
for(5,9)
5, 6, 7, 8, 9                
for(6,1)
6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
```

Comment: You appear to have overlooked quoting the parameters, e.g., using `[` and `]`

Comment: @Thomas Dickey. The m4 I'm using uses backtick  & apostrophe (`') as delimiters. Putting the params inside delimiters made no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `m4` encounters `foo(3,9)`, it expands that to the text of the `ifelse` as defined in the macro.  In order to invoke `ifelse`, it has to pass arguments to it.  To determine those arguments, it has to expand `eval`.  Hence the error message.

You can avoid the error message with:

```
define(`for',
`ifelse(
        `$#', `2', `for(`$1', `$2', `1')',
        eval(`$1' + ifelse(`$3', `', `0', `1') > `$2'), `1', `$1',
        `$1, for(eval(`$1' + `$3'), `$2', `$3')'dnl
)')dnl
```

Comment: Thanks William that clears it up for me. A simpler example makes it clearer. Setting define(`xx',`ifelse($#,1,$1,incr($2))') and calling xx(8) shows the error.